# 'R: Invalid use of repetition operators'

Tags: regex, r

I'm writing a small function in R as follows:

```
    tags.out <- as.character(tags.out)
    tags.out.unique <- unique(tags.out)
    z <- NROW(tags.out.unique)

    for (i in 1:10) {
       l <- length(grep(tags.out.unique[i], x = tags.out))
       tags.count <- append(x = tags.count, values = l) }
```

Basically I'm looking to take each element of the unique character vector (tags.out.unique) and count it's occurrence in the vector prior to the `unique` function.

This above section of code works correctly, however, when I replace `for (i in 1:10)` with `for (i in 1:z)` or even some number larger than 10 (18000 for example) I get the following error:

`Error in grep(tags.out.unique[i], x = tags.out) : 
  invalid regular expression 'c++', reason 'Invalid use of repetition operators`

I would be extremely grateful if anyone were able to help me understand what's going on here.

Many thanks.

Comment: "take each element of the [...] character vector [...] and count it's occurrence [...]" `table(tags.out)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would appear that one of the elements of `tags.out_unique` is `c++` which is (as the error message plainly states) an invalid regular expression.

You are currently programming inefficiently. The [R-inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) is worth a read, noting especially that Growing objects is generally bad form -- it can be extremely inefficient in some cases. If you are going to have a blanket rule, then "not growing objects" is a better one than "avoid loops".

Given you are simply trying to count the number of times each value occurs there is no need for the loop or regex

```
counts <- table(tags.out) 
# the unique values
names(counts)
```

should give you the results you want.

Answer (score 14):

The "+" in "c++" (which you're passing to grep as a pattern string) has a special meaning. However, you want the "+" to be interpreted literally as the character "+", so instead of

```
grep(pattern="c++", x="this string contains c++")
```

you should do

```
grep(pattern="c++", x="this string contains c++", fixed=TRUE)
```

If you google [regex special characters] or something similar, you'll see that "+", "*" and many others have a special meaning. In your case you want them to be interpreted literally -- see ?grep.